# e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3

Tags: probe

LAN network is not getting up daily in morning after boot in Debian 11
HI i am using debian 11 bullseye and in morning when i start the pc i get a cable unplugged sign in the network

In syslog the error is

> Aug 29 09:10:25 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.378763] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
> Aug 29 09:10:25 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.378766] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
> Aug 29 09:10:25 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.383352] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
> Aug 29 09:10:25 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    2.403346] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3

But after half hour the nic card was up

> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.375644] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.375645] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.375805] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.453727] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.522717] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 78:2b:cb:b8:75:48
> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.522719] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.522752] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
> Aug 29 09:52:40 782bcbb87548 kernel: [    1.795363] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
> Aug 29 09:52:47 782bcbb87548 kernel: [   67.961753] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None

```
lspci -v | grep -A9 Ether
```

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I217-LM
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28, IOMMU group 5
    Memory at f7c00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at f7c3d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Any help or guide is welcome

I am unable to resolve this issue
.

Kernel : 6.1.0-0.deb11.9-amd64( previously it was 5.10 so i upgraded the kernel)

Comment: Does the network come back after a soft reboot ?